# How to perform a SQL Search String in String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How should I  can search a string in a string?

For example:

- List item

Status changed from `'Open'` to `'Closed'`

The new column should return `"Closed"`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add sample data and your current query to the question.

Comment: Query: Select id, description from db.dbo.tickets / The description column contains the string above

Answer (score 0):

Searching a string in a string would work with:

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

[CHARINDEX Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: How do you even know the OP is using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it´s MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

You havent provided enough context to properly answer your question, sample data etc. but here is something you could start with.

```
SELECT 'Closed' AS [NEW_STATUS], *
FROM [YourTable]
WHERE [STATUS] -- or whatever the name of the column is that contains the status change text
LIKE "%to 'Closed'%"
```

Alternate solution depending on your situation:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN [StatusText] LIKE "%to 'Closed%"
     THEN 'Closed'
     WHEN [StatusText] LIKE "%to 'Open%"
     THEN 'Open'
END AS [CurrentStatus]
FROM [YourTable]
```

Comment: Thanks :) But the output should be the value not a fixed string.

Comment: And the values "open" and "Closed" are examples. They can be different.